# System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary missing in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to implement functionality using HybridDictionary in Xamarin Forms.  I can add reference of System.Collections.Specialized but its missing  HybridDictionary class definition. I can see Only

INotifyCollectionChanged 
NotifyCollectionChangedAction 
NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs 
NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler

I can  use other collections except this. Am I missing any thing to add?

Comment: Have you tried to create a `netstandard` library and consume it? https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Specialized/ seems to support `netstandard 1.3`

Comment: @yugali-bhavsar-bharote if my answer worked for you mark it as correct, so others can achieve it. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HybridDictionary` in platform specific projects like, `Android` and `iOS`.

I tested it on every PCL profile and it isn't available. You could try to pull it as reference from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Specialized/).